# Kotlin android app is not showing notification

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I am building an Android app using Kotlin. I am trying to show notification following this tutorial because I want to support the older versions of the Android as well, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/notifications-in-kotlin/. But it is not showing the notification.

This is my main activity to show notification

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManager
    lateinit var notificationChannel: NotificationChannel
    lateinit var builder: Notification.Builder
    private val channelId = "i.apps.notifications"
    private val description = "Test notification"
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        //seedTestData()
        showNotification()


    }

    private fun showNotification() {
        val intent = Intent(this, MessageDetailsActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(MessageDetailsActivity.KEY_MESSAGE, "Test message")

        // FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT specifies that if a previous
        // PendingIntent already exists, then the current one
        // will update it with the latest intent
        // 0 is the request code, using it later with the
        // same method again will get back the same pending
        // intent for future reference
        // intent passed here is to our afterNotification class
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        // RemoteViews are used to use the content of
        // some different layout apart from the current activity layout
        val contentView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.activity_message_details)

        // checking if android version is greater than oreo(API 26) or not
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, description, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
            notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(false)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

            builder = Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setContent(contentView)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        } else {

            builder = Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContent(contentView)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        }
        notificationManager.notify(1234, builder.build())
    }

}
```

This is my activity_message_details.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:id="@+id/message_details_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/accent_color"
                android:id="@+id/message_details_share_button"
                android:text="SHARE_MESSAGE"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the code, it is not showing the notification. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried with another device ?

Comment: Hi, yes, I did. But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've ran your code I received this error:

```
Bad notification posted from package com.sandbox.myapplication:
Couldn not inflate contentViewsandroid.view.InflateException:
Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9:
Error inflating class android.widget.ScrollView
```

and app crashed.

The problem is that you are using `android.widget.ScrollView` `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton` in your layout, and this is layout for the `RemoteView`. For `RemoteViews` you can use only classes and widgets listed here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

If you will remove `android.widget.ScrollView` and `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton` from the layout all should work.

So you need to restruct your layout using classes and widgets from the list.